# Understanding try & catch and error handling

Tags: java, error-handling, try-catch

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab4_5 {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);

        int rows=0;
        int rowIndex=0, colIndex=0;
        boolean choice1= true;
        String y="y";
        String n="n";
        boolean first = true;

        while (choice1==true) {
            if (first==true) {  
                first=false;
                System.out.println("Do you want to start(Y/N): ");
            } else if (first==false) {
                System.out.println("Do you want to continue(Y/N): ");
            }

            String choice2=scan.next();
            if (choice2.equals(y)) {
                System.out.println("How many rows/columns(5-21)?");
                rows=scan.nextInt();
                while (rows<5 || rows>21) {
                    System.out.println("That is either out of range or not an integer, try again! ");
                    rows=scan.nextInt();
                }

                System.out.println("What character?");
                String choice3=scan.next();
                System.out.println(" ");

                for (rowIndex=1; rowIndex<=rows; rowIndex++) {
                    for (colIndex=1; colIndex<=rows; colIndex++) {
                        if (rowIndex==1 || rowIndex==rows || colIndex==1 || colIndex==rows) {
                            System.out.print(choice3);
                        } else {
                            System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            } else if(choice2.equals(n)) {
                choice1 = false;
                System.out.println("Thank you. Goodbye.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please either enter Y or N.");
            }
        }
    }//end of main 
}
```

The code prints what I need it to print, but I also have to have something in the code when it asks how many rows/columns to catch whether or not i input something other than an integer(in the part below). need some help, we haven't done anything yet with how to catch exceptions and i don't know how to start.

```
String choice2=scan.next();
if (choice2.equals(y)) {
    System.out.println("How many rows/columns(5-21)?");
    rows=scan.nextInt();
    while (rows<5 || rows>21) {
        System.out.println("That is either out of range or not an integer, try again! ");
        rows=scan.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting an exception or you just want to know how to have the code run more readable?

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) please look into it.

Basic understanding is

```
try { 
   //Something that can throw an exception.
} catch (Exception e) {
  // To do whatever when the exception is caught.
}
```

There is also an finally block which will always be execute even if there is an error. it is used like this

```
try { 
   //Something that can throw an exception.
} catch (Exception e) {
  // To do whatever when the exception is caught & the returned.
} finally {
  // This will always execute if there is an exception or no exception.
}
```

In your particular case you can have the following exceptions ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt())).

InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range
NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted
IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed

So you would need to catch exceptions like

```
try { 
   rows=scan.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
  // When the InputMismatchException is caught.
  System.out.println("The next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range");
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
  // When the NoSuchElementException is caught.
  System.out.println("Input is exhausted");
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
  // When the IllegalStateException is caught.
  System.out.println("Scanner is close");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a try-catch block like so:

```
try {
    int num = scan.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
    // Exception handling here
}
```

If you want to implement this in your code, I suggest doing this:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        rows = scan.nextInt();
        if (rows<5||rows>21) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("That is either out of range or not an integer, try again! ");
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.println("That is either out of range or not an integer, try again! ");
    }
}
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html) for more details.

Answer (score -2):

```
String choice2=scan.next();
if(choice2.equals(y)){
  System.out.println("How many rows/columns(5-21)?");
try
{
rows=scan.nextInt();
}catch(Exception e)
{
rows = -1;
}
 while(rows<5||rows>21){
  System.out.println("That is either out of range or not an integer, try again! ");
try
{
rows=scan.nextInt();
}catch(Exception e)
{
rows = -1;
}
}
```

Comment: -1, you should rarely (if _ever_) catch `Exception` directly.

Comment: -1 @Brian S - In this case he doesn't care what the Exception is if there is an exception he wants to reprompt the user for input it doesn't matter why its wrong and yes there are cases to catch Exception you are wrong!

Comment: OP is just learning, so a good answer would teach. Aeshang's answer is a good example of teaching how to use exceptions: it shows the basic syntax, and the full syntax for the specific use-case. There are cases where using `Exception` is fine, but most of the time it's simply a crutch for bad code, and that's not something you want to pass out to new programmers.