# Try/Catch variable can't be initialized

Tags: java, loops, variables, try-catch, java.util.scanner

I'm having an issue with my try/catch blocks. Now, my code works somewhat, however, when I enter in an invalid number ("a") for example, I have the program print out, ("please enter a valid number: "); But, I have a method that gets the object at the entered index and it's stating the local variable may not have been initialized.

```
do {
        int firstNum;
        int secondNum;
        int thirdNum;
        System.out
                .println("Please enter three of the numbers you see on the left of the shape:");
        try {

            firstNum = scan.nextInt();
            secondNum = scan.nextInt();
            thirdNum = scan.nextInt();

            Card card = Deck.randomizedCards.get(firstNum);
            Card card1 = Deck.randomizedCards.get(secondNum);
            Card card2 = Deck.randomizedCards.get(thirdNum);
            if (Deck.isSet(card, card1, card2) == true) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "You found a set!");
                Deck.completedSets.add(card);
                Deck.completedSets.add(card1);
                Deck.completedSets.add(card2);

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel,
                        "You didn't find a set");
            }
             break;
        } catch (InputMismatchException name) {
            System.out
                    .println("You have entered an invalid number, please enter a number:");

        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException name) {
            System.out
                    .println("You have entered an invalid number, please enter a number:");

        }

    } while (true);
```

Comment: Which variable on which line does the error specify?

Comment: Where should the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` come from?

Comment: Card card = Deck.randomizedCards.get(firstNum);
    Card card1 = Deck.randomizedCards.get(secondNum);
    Card card2 = Deck.randomizedCards.get(thirdNum); These variables in the parameters are not initialized.

Comment: If the user enters in a -1 or 13, then that's bigger than the arrays size.

Comment: @AndrewBuxa You're not using any array inside the try block. So there is no chance that this exception block will be reached.

Comment: Instead of changing the "old" code you should add the new version. Now the answers might became invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem lies in this code fragment

```
try{
   firstNum= scan.nextInt();
.
.
.
catch (InputMismatchException name) {
    System.out.println("You have entered an invalid number, please enter a number (Range 1-11): ");

}
```

when the input exception is thrown the offending input was left on the stream so when the execution reached scan.nextInt() again it got the same bad input and therefore threw the same exception and so on. Change the catch block to be:

```
 catch (InputMismatchException name) {
  String malformedGarbage = scan.Next();//processes the bad input so the scanner can move on.  
  System.out.println("You have entered an invalid number, please enter a number (Range 1-11): ");
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the assignment in the `try` statement might not occur you have your variables `firstNum`, `secondNum`, `thirdNum` left potentially unititialized.

You can circumvent that by either assigning a default value or by moving logic into the same `try` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is (correctly) warning you that variables such as `thirdNum` might not have been initialized when, for example, the line `secondNum = scan.nextInt();` throws an exception.

To circumvent this problem you should assign default values to all of your variables, or make the method return when an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

```
int firstNum;
int secondNum;
int thirdNum;
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter three of the numbers you see on the left of the shape:");
    try {
       firstNum = scan.nextInt();
       secondNum = scan.nextInt();
       thirdNum = scan.nextInt();
       Card card = Deck.randomizedCards.get(firstNum);
       Card card1 = Deck.randomizedCards.get(secondNum);
       Card card2 = Deck.randomizedCards.get(thirdNum);
       if (Deck.isSet(card, card1, card2)) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "You found a set!");
           Deck.completedSets.add(card);
           Deck.completedSets.add(card1);
           Deck.completedSets.add(card2);
           break;  
        } else {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "You didn't find a set");
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException name) {
        System.out
                .println("You have entered an invalid number, please enter a number (Range 1-11): ");

    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException name) {
        System.out
                .println("You have entered an invalid number, please enter a number(Range 1-11): ");
    }
} while (true);
```

Comment: I tried running the code, and I got an infinite loop of println statements asking for a number.

Comment: Ofcourse if you run a loop with while(true) and no break statement. Check the edit.

Comment: I see, I added in the break statement, but I'm still getting the infinite loop. I'm trying to make the user continuously enter the indexes of the displayed cards.

Comment: Can you share your new code in the question will be easier to see what you have done.

Comment: Put the break in if cause when they guess it you want to stop ? if not find the appropriate condition to stop.

Comment: I'd like the program to check if the three indexes the user entered are number, if they are, then the isSet method runs to check if the cards(at indexes selected) are true or false. Based on that, the program will prompt the user for three numbers again. But I'm having difficulty understanding the logic behind doing this.

Comment: You need to share the card and deck class as well more importantly you need to share Deck.isSet method. Check the edit if it works ...   if (Deck.isSet(card, card1, card2)) { you don't need   if (Deck.isSet(card, card1, card2) == true) {

Comment: It's still not working. Here's my Deck and Card class. http://pastebin.com/ufRueGVr

Comment: IT WORKS FINE FOR ME DONT KNOW WHAT YOU SAYING ? check this http://pastebin.com/rY6Pd2py

Comment: I don't understand. I'm typing in ("a") for the first number and it just turns into an infinite loop of printlns.

Comment: please use number as you are doing next int when you type a then it goes in the catch block and continues the loop execution.

Comment: Okay, so lets say the user is trying to break the program. He types in a instead of a number. What I have will handle the exception and will ask the user for a number within the index. But for some reason, I keep getting an infinite loop.

Comment: Dude that loop is for that to ask them for another input until the guess correctly or enter an invalid input. If they guess wrong you keep asking them to guess. Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25940409/1085186 hope this clears out doubts.